# Pull back of the laplacian using differential form.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, pullback

Given a smooth manifold $\mathcal{M}$ a way to express of expressing the Laplacian operator $\Delta$ is through the combination of differentials and hodge star operator $\star$
$$
\Delta f = \star d \star d f
$$

Suppose we have a smooth manifold $\mathcal{N}$ and a smooth map $F : \mathcal{N} \to \mathcal{M}$ then $F$ induces a pullback $F^* : \Omega^k(\mathcal{M}) \to \Omega^k(N)$. Among the known properties of the pullback two are worth to mention, the commutativity with the exterior derivative $d$ operator and the distribution w.r.t. the wedge product.

**Question** Does it however commute with the $\star$ operator? doing this would allow me to perform things like?

$$
F^* \star d \star d f = \star d \star d F^* f
$$

which I think is a very useful property.

Comment: The Hodge star is defined thanks to the data of a Riemannian metric. If you want $f\colon N \to M$ to respect the respective Hodge stars, you better ask for $f$ to be an isometry I guess

Comment: You think is mandatory?

Comment: I have no concrete proof, but I'd put my 2 cents on it

Comment: If  $k=n/2$ where $n=\dim M=\dim N$ then it suffices to require that $f$ is a conformal map since $\star$ is conformally invariant in those dimensions.